# Create HTML from two XML files

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to create a brochure for a conference. I export information from two databases that  create two XML documents. I need to export both to one HTML / Latex document. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge both the XML in one. Then you need to convert both XML's to JSON object using javascript. And do some merging operations on that JSON. Then convert back to XML.
U can get JS libraries to convert from json to xml and xml to json.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/transformation#summary) is for but that topic is something you will need to study up on to learn to do that and it isn't something you'll learn overnight.